# Cannot ping localhost

Tags: macos, dns

I have setup a new MacBook Pro retina, things were going well but now I cannot access localhost.

```
$ ping localhost
ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host
```

My /etc/hosts file is fine, or at least untouched.

I have tried flushing the DNS cache, and `dig localhost` spits out

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 50562
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           1551    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2013030800 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar  8 14:53:09 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 102
```

I am at a loss what to try next!
I have even run OnyX to clean all cache etc...

Comment: can you ping 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yep that works fine

Comment: do you use firewalls like little snitch?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your host file got mangled. Open a terminal, and read your hosts file:

```
vim /private/etc/hosts
```

This should contain a line that maps `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

It could be this file does not exist at all, or the line I gave above is not present. To be able to edit it you need to be superuser, i.e.:

```
sudo vim /private/etc/hosts
```

or you can use any other editor besides `vim`.

Comment: It seems /private/etc/hosts just opens up /etc/hosts, which contains 
127.0.0.1 localhost etc...
as you would expect

Answer (score 0):

Searching `man ...`

- `hosts` (/etc/hosts), I see that

> The hosts file is read by mDNSResponder(8) and used to supply results for calls to getaddrinfo(3), getnameinfo(3), etc.
> in addition to results obtained from multicast and unicast DNS.

- `dig` & `host`, only mention `/etc/resolv.conf`, and contain no mention of `etc` or `hosts`.

`/etc/resolv.conf` says it's not used for most DNS lookups on the system (system networking library calls), and suggests `scutil --dns` and to `SEE ALSO dns-sd(1), scutil(8)`.

I'm stuck with the same weird issue that I can't get ICMP replies from localhost nor the IP on en0, the local Wi-Fi LAN interface.

Perhaps it's something in firewall settings. Or hopefully not, other system security permissions.